# Overriding a link underline for a particuliar div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a `<div>` inside a `<a>`, that I don't want to be underlined.

HTML :

```
<a href="/joomla17/contact">
  <div class="button">nous contacter</div>
</a>
```

A generic `a` rule is defined elsewhere.

I tried this with css :

```
.button {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

but it is still underlined. Checked with Firebug that the `text-decoration: none` isn't overridden.

I feel that I have to specify `a:link`, but I don't know how to make it match my class

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make the a `display: block;` and remove this unnecessary div?

Comment: @BloodyWorld: my div already has a `display:inline`, so will it conflict?

Comment: a is an inline element by default, why use a inline'd div here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `div` with `display: inline;`, its not necessary because `a` is an inline element by default. So why put an inline container inside an inline element?

```
<a class="button" href="/joomla17/contact">nous contacter</a>
```

But maybe you have some special reasons for that build, so this could be an solution with the div. Since the `div` is inside the `a`, it inherits the properties of `a`, so normally it should inherit the underline thing too. But maybe you need to set that on the div explicitly.

```
.button, .button div { text-decoration:none; }
```

Maybe you need to add `!important` in front of the `;`, depends on the complexity of your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.button{text-decoration:none !important;}
```

to avoid that your style is overriden by any following rule.

If you want to use pseudo classes on your a-element it would look  like this:

```
a:link{/* ... */} 
a:active{/* ... */} 
a:hover{/* ... */}
a:visited{/* ... */}
```

and if you want to access the div when the link has a specific state use

```
a:hover .button{/* ... */}
```

for instance.

Comment: Why do I get down voted? My answer is technically correct and as long as the asker doesn't provide any more details I can't see any reason why my answer isn't considered to be right.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it didn't work, sorry but I can't tell you why

Comment: I think your solution does not work because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18493630/143295