# Span inside td does not override td style

Tags: html, css

I have a `span` tag inside a `td`. The `td` has a class with CSS to set the `text-decoration` to `underline`, while the `span` sets the `text-decoration` to `none`. I expect the text inside the `span` to not be underlined, but for some reason it is. Why?

```css
.u {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.no-u {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="u">
            <span class="no-u" style="text-decoration: none !important;">My Text</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The span doesn't have an underline; the table cell just still has the underline. In other words, the underline is being applied to the cell, not the span, so your rule on the span has no noticeable effect.

Comment: Accoeding to @j08691 comment, just try to set `text-decoration: overline;` on the span, you'll see *underlne* and *overline* both together: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/mfV5V/3/

Comment: You may find useful this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113520/text-decorationnone-doesnt-remove-text-decoration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cannot remove the underlined style for descendants.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props

> The 'text-decoration' property on descendant elements cannot have any
>   effect on the decoration of the ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

According to the CSS2 spec, http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props:

> For block containers that establish an inline formatting context, the decorations are propagated to an anonymous inline element that wraps all the in-flow inline-level children of the block container.

This means that that any text and any inline element like `<b>`, `<em>` and `<span>` are all wrapped in an anonymous inline box on which the text decoration is applied.

Furthermore, in the case of a child inline-element, you can apply another text decoration which allows you to have both underline and overline appearing on a span of text.  In this case, the underline in painted on one anonymous inline box and the overline is painted on a second (nested) anonymous inline box.

In this example, the `td` element acts as the block container.

However, this does not apply to `inline-blocks`.

See the demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/MSUHx/